# How to INSERT to a column name in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to INSERT to a column name in Snowflake

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
TO  DATE,
FROM DATE
)
```

I am getting the error:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 0 unexpected 'TO'. syntax error line 4 at position 0 unexpected 'FROM'

Comment: No need to shout, even if the question is about SQL.

Comment: While SQL statements are usually written in all upper-case, normal sentences should not be. That's considered shouting, and it's very rude to shout at the people you want to help you.

Comment: As noted by others, avoid reserved words like the plague.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( "TO" DATE, "FROM" DATE );
```

However, I would recommend a column name like TO_DATE or FROM_DATE instead of using the keyword FROM. If you SELECT from the table, you also need to use "" as a consequence.

Answer (score 0):

Use double Quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( "TO" DATE, "FROM" DATE );
```

Comment: Be careful... Your quotes are not really correct either.